# How to call angular bundle files from c#?

Tags: c#, angular, typescript

I am building a c# angular application. Currently I am calling my scripts inside the layout.cshtml file with.

```
<script src="~/bundles/runtime.js"></script>
<script src="~/bundles/polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="~/bundles/vendor.js"></script>
<script src="~/bundles/scripts.js"></script>
<script src="~/bundles/main.js"></script>
```

This causes issues when I try to deploy my app and these files are instead named main.2398saa929, etc. In my deployed app it still makes calls to runtime.js, polyfills.js etc. I've tried adding

I'm wondering if there is another way to do this bundling call so it works both locally and on deployed server.

Answer (score 0):

Bundling and minifying a website's scripts and stylesheets reduces page load time and asset size. Here's my project setup for bundling and minifying scripts of an AngularJS application hosted within an ASP.NET MVC site.
Kindly follow the instruction here https://mariusschulz.com/blog/bundling-and-minifying-an-angularjs-application-with-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

Edit your package.json, in scripts, the build, you can add --outputHashing=none. So becomes like:

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod=true --outputHashing=none --namedChunks=false --vendorChunk=false",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

NOTE: I'm not sure, but I think that in Angular 6, the way was changing the change the angular.json. In configurations-->production, change outputHasshig to none

```
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "none",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          ...
```